# Swift Socket Programming Passing Strings to Java Server (ServerSocket)

Tags: java, ios, swift, sockets, server

This is code that I have for a java server:

```
public class ServerMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Server Initialized");
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket so = s.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection made");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(so.getOutputStream(), false);
        String message = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("message: " + message);

        if(message.equals("NBA")){
            Lineup lineup = Utils.createLineup(Utils.readCSV("CSV/DraftKings/NBADKSalaries.csv"),"NBA");
            ArrayList<Player> players = lineup.printLineup();
            for(Player p : players){
                out.print(p.getName()+" ");
            }
            out.flush();
        }

        else if(message.equals("NFL")){
            Lineup lineup = Utils.createLineup(Utils.readCSV("CSV/DraftKings/NFLDKSalaries.csv"),"NFL");
            ArrayList<Player> players = lineup.printLineup();
            for(Player p : players){
                out.print(p.getName()+" ");
            }
            out.flush();
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Unintelligible message from the client: " +message);
            out.println("error");
        }
        s.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can get the server to react to my swift code (with a NullPointerException albeit because message is always null):

```
func connect() {

    var readStream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    let mystring = "NFL"

    let data: NSData = mystring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let host : CFString = NSString(string: "192.168.2.1")//(string: self.host)
    let port : UInt32 = UInt32(1234)//(self.port)

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()

//        inputStream!.delegate = self
//        outputStream!.delegate = self

    inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream!.open()
    outputStream!.open()

    outputStream!.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)

    inputStream!.close()
    outputStream!.close()

}
```

I have a very rough understanding of socket programming, but how would I be able to pass in to my java server from my swift code so that "message" in my java server code would equal "NFL"? Also, how would I receive information back from the java server (a raw string) that I could use in my Swift code?